# RxJava2: Repeat conditonally / don't repeat in `repeatWhen`

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have a Observable I want to repeat periodically, but only under a condition:

```
apiInterface.getData() // returns Observable<Data>
... // processing is happening here
.toList()
.repeatWhen(completed -> {
    if (autoReload){
        // Repeat every 3 seconds
        return completed.delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } else {
        return ??? // What do I have to return that it does not repeat?
    }
})
.subscribe(list -> callbackInterface.success(list));
```

My question is: What do I have to return in the `else` statement to not repeat the Observable (just execute the chain once)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to **react to the completion indicator** by something that signals completion in response to an item, for example:

```
completed.takeWhile(v -> false);
```

Unfortunately, `empty()` doesn't work there because it immediately completes the sequence before the source could even run.

Answer (score 0):

It's `Observable.empty()`. As stated in Javadoc documentation:

> [..] If that Observable calls `onComplete` or `onError` then `repeatWhen` will call `onCompleted` or `onError` on the child subscription. Otherwise, this Observable will resubscribe to the source observable.

So complete code is:

```
apiInterface.getData() // returns Observable<Data>
... // processing is happening here
.toList()
.repeatWhen(completed -> {
    if (autoReload){
        // Repeat every 3 seconds
        return completed.delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } else {
        return Observable.empty()
    }
})
.subscribe(list -> callbackInterface.success(list));
```

Comment: Using your suggestion (I had to use `Flowable.empty()`) it never calls `onNext` with the result, it just calls `onCompleted`. I need it to run once not never. Thank you for the idea though!